# multiple while loop comparison (BigDecimal and > 10 )

Tags: java, bigdecimal, compareto

This is my first post and I have been searching google and stack overflow for the past 24 hours and can not seem to pin down my problem.

I am creating a simple square root program.  For the input section I start a 'while' loop.  I need it to compare two conditions.
1. is the input a number
2. is the input a number over ten.

I was successful in creating the original program, however I ran into a small problem while debugging.  When I put in a vary large decimal or number I would get a run time error.

I discovered that I could use BigDecimal() to solve this problem.

However I am now running into a logic error that I cannot solve no matter how many times I search the internet.

The two conditions that I use in the while loop are:

```
    while (!scan.hasNextBigDecimal() || (inputNumberBig.compareTo(SENTINAL)>0))
```

This will make sure that there is a BigDecimal, but will not make sure that the input number is over ten.

Here is the whole program

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 @author Mike
 */

public class SquareRootingWithoutBigDecimal 
{
public static void main( String [] args )
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    double inputNumber = 0.00;
    double rootedNumber = inputNumber;

     BigDecimal inputNumberBig = new BigDecimal(0.00);
     BigDecimal SENTINAL = new BigDecimal(10.00);
     String garbage;
     double garbageD = 0.00;


        System.out.println("Please Enter a number to be Square rooted"
            + "\nThe number must be 10 or greater ");       
        while (!scan.hasNextBigDecimal() || (inputNumberBig.compareTo(SENTINAL)>0))
        {

        garbage = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please Enter a number to be Square rooted"
            + "\nThe number must be 10 or greater ");
        }

    inputNumberBig = scan.nextBigDecimal();
    inputNumber = inputNumberBig.doubleValue();  



    rootedNumber = inputNumber;
    do
    {
        rootedNumber = Math.sqrt(rootedNumber);
        System.out.println(rootedNumber);

    } while (rootedNumber >= 1.01 );

}
```

Any and all help is much appreciated.

-Mike

Comment: While most of your code is probably relevant to this question, to be polite (and increase your chances of getting an answer) I would strip off the import statements and the leading comments with the author tag.

Comment: what specifically is the problem?

Comment: Strip useless comments: yes. Strip necessary imports: no. Format code properly: yes. Also, what exactly is your question?

Comment: @RyanStewart I stand corrected.  It is easier to copy-paste and try out code if it is compile ready.

Comment: Try using `&&` instead of `||`. Without knowing the actual problem, I could see this maybe causing one

Comment: @peeskillet - I used the && and am still getting the above problem

Comment: The problem that I am having is that the program will still exit the loop if the input variable is less than 10

Comment: @User, check my answer, I think I found your problem

Comment: In plain language, do you want the input to be BigDecimal AND less than 10?  Or do you want it to be EITHER BigDecimal OR less than 10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
inputNumberBig = scan.nextBigDecimal();
inputNumber = inputNumberBig.doubleValue();
```

These HAVE to go before you `while` loop for your logic to work.

Also,

```
while (!scan.hasNextBigDecimal() || (inputNumberBig.compareTo(SENTINAL)>0))
```

I could see this causing a problem.  You should use `&&` instead of `||`

Comment: I use the advise but I am still having a problem with the while loop exiting if the number is under 10.

Comment: I am still having a problem with the loop exiting if the input number is under ten.  I updated the code with the above advise

Comment: But don't you want the number to BE less than ten?

Comment: oh, no the number needs to be greater than or equal to ten.

Comment: Ok, then if you want the program to exit, leave the `(inputNumberBig.compareTo(SENTINAL)>0)` in your while loop like you originally had it, but use `&&` instead of `||`.  And change it to `(inputNumberBig.compareTo(SENTINAL) >= 0)` Notice the `>=`.

Comment: I thought that's what you want. You said the number must be greater than 10.

Comment: I update the code as suggested and am still running into the same problem.

Comment: And what problem is that?

Comment: I apologize,
If I enter 0-9 the program will still squareroot the number, instead of staying in the loop.

Comment: Ok, I think you have to put your `do/while` loop inside of you first `while` loop.  I THINK that's what you're looking for.

Comment: I was able to solve this problem thanks to you. I use the condition of `while (!(scan.hasNextBigDecimal() && (inputNumberBig.compareTo(SENTINAL) >=0)))`  Thank you for the help